# Java callback functions as parameter

Tags: java, callback, inline

I'd like to do something simple, but I can't express it in a google search. So, I come here ^^

I have an Async task like this :

```
class RequestTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    final MyCallbackInterface callback;

    RequestTask(MyCallbackInterface callback) {
        this.callback = callback;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... uri) {
        ...
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        callback.onTaskFinished(result);
    }
}

interface MyCallbackInterface {
    void onTaskFinished(String result);
}
```

So, I have a task with a callback to execute when the task ends.

Now I can call it like this :

```
class Program {

    public void DoAsyncRequest(String stringUrl, MyCallbackInterface callback) {
        new RequestTask(callback).execute(stringUrl);
    }

    public static void Main(){

        DoAsyncRequest("http://toto.com", new MyCallbackInterface() {

            @Override
            public void onDownloadFinished(String result) {
                //do something ...
            }
        });
    }
}
```

But, instead of having an "inline" function as callback, is it possible to do something like this : (if yes, how ?)

```
class Program {

    public void DoAsyncRequest(String stringUrl, MyCallbackInterface callback) {
        new RequestTask(callback).execute(stringUrl);
    }

    public static void Main(){

         DoAsyncRequest("http://toto.com", MyCallBack);
    }

    private void MyCallBack(string result){
        //do something
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a static class:

```
private static class MyCallback implements MyCallbackInterface  {

        @Override
        public void onDownloadFinished(String result) {
            //do something ...
        }
}
```

and then call using

```
DoAsyncRequest("http://toto.com", new MyCallBack());
```

You can't do

```
private void MyCallBack(string result){
    //do something
}
```

as your callback is expected to be one of the object type and not method. Also it's not inline method, it's anonymous class that we call and which is much similar to class defined above except it doesn't have any name but you are implementing the method by overriding.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your callback method as static and then use reflection to call it. The main thing you miss in that solution is type safety though; You could pass the class to be called on task finish as MyClass.class then.